# angular using ng-click in a select tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-select, angularjs-ng-click

I want a dropdown list to change the language my site is displayed in, so I currently have:

```
<select ng-controller="langCtrl">
     <option ng-click="switchLanguage('en')" value="en">EN</option>
     <option ng-click="switchLanguage('de')" value="de">DE</option>
     <option ng-click="switchLanguage('it')" value="it">IT</option>
     <option ng-click="switchLanguage('fr')" value="fr">FR</option>
     <option ng-click="switchLanguage('es')" value="es">ES</option>
</select>
```

However for some reasons these `ng-click`s don't seem to be calling the specified function. I changed them all to buttons, and that seemed to work fine, but I want a dropdown list, not buttons. Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

Controller code:

```
app.controller('langCtrl', function($translate, $location, $scope) {
$scope.switchLanguage = function (langKey) {
    switch(langKey) {
        case 'en':
            $location.url('/#en');
            break;
        case 'de':
            $location.url('/#de');
            break;
        case 'it':
            $location.url('/#it');
            break;
        case 'fr':
            $location.url('/#fr');
            break;
        case 'es':
            $location.url('/#es');
            break;
        default:
            $location.url('/#en');
    }
    $translate.use(langKey);
  };
});
```

Comment: Can you add your controller code?

Comment: Isn't this where you would use something more like `ng-change` and `ng-model` on the `select` itself?

Comment: @nikhil updated to include controller code.

Comment: @user2412643 - You already have answers now. Here is a plunker for your reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/ZTJkg4IeiDYzOvGAohcP?p=preview

Comment: @user2412643 - Additionally, your last option is closed with button tag. Please correct that too

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A proper way to do this would be using ng-model

```js
angular.module('test', [])

.controller('langCtrl', function($scope, $location/*, $translate*/) {
  $scope.switchLanguage = function() {
    langKey = $scope.selected;
    
    switch (langKey) {
      case 'en':
        alert('/#en');
        //$location.url('/#en');
        break;
      case 'de':
        alert('/#de');
        //$location.url('/#de');
        break;
      case 'it':
        alert('/#it');
        //$location.url('/#it');
        break;
      case 'fr':
        alert('/#fr');
        //$location.url('/#fr');
        break;
      case 'es':
        alert('/#es');
        //$location.url('/#es');
        break;
      default:
        alert('/#en');
        //$location.url('/#en');
    }
    //$translate.use(langKey);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<select ng-app='test' ng-controller="langCtrl" ng-model="selected" ng-change="switchLanguage()">
  <option value="en">EN</option>
  <option value="de">DE</option>
  <option value="it">IT</option>
  <option value="fr">FR</option>
  <option value="es">ES</option>
</select>
```

Not sure why your example doesn't work though, it looks fine.

Comment: Beat me to it. `option` doesn't support onClick, so maybe that's why? Select boxes should be done this way anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @icycool - doesn't seem to be working though :( the function still isn't called with the correct argument

Comment: @user2412643 I've updated with snippet. Corrected ending tag on ES option.

Comment: I copied your code exactly and it's still not working right - I updated my original question to include the code for the controller, do you have any idea why this is? Thanks again man.

Comment: updated to follow the structure. If this still doesn't work, then it is not because of the select anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can using with `ng-model` and `ng-change`

Try this

```
<div  ng-controller="langCtrl">
<select ng-change="switchLanguage(ModelName)" ng-model="ModelName">
     <option value="en">EN</option>
     <option value="de">DE</option>
     <option value="it">IT</option>
     <option value="fr">FR</option>
     <option value="es">ES</button>
</select>
</div>
```

controller

```
$scope.switchLanguage = function(ModelName)
{
   var seletedValue = ModelName;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to pass model's reference in `ng-change`